# Eclipse e4/rcp missing items

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, equinox, e4

I want to start developing Eclipse 4 apps. So I have downloaded the eclipse 4.3.1, and the e4 tools from [here](http://download.eclipse.org/e4/downloads/drops/R-0.14-201306242200/index.html). Unfortunately when I try to create a plug-in project the following errors appears:

```
 Operation details - Cannot complete the install because one or more required items can't be found : 
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director and org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I recommend you used to Eclipse software update sites, from inside Eclipse, and not manually instead stuff yourself.

Comment: The current e4 tools update site is http://download.eclipse.org/e4/updates/0.15-I-builds

Comment: well this is what i have done ... also if I check for updates it says that everything is up to data

Comment: Is there any more in the .log? I think this may be the 0.14 tools you used require older versions of plugins. I believe the 0.15 tools are need for 4.3.1